# WPF How to set a maximum amount of results from CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, itemscontrol, collectionviewsource

I am trying to display a set of data using a `DataTemplate` in an `ItemsControl`, with the `ItemsPanel` set as a uniform grid of size 3 x 3. The `ItemsSource` of the `ItemsControl` is set to bind to a `CollectionViewSource` which filters the source collection based on a search term. This all works fine.

The list I am binding to is of an arbitrary size, but I only want 9 results to be displayed, but I can't for the life of me work out how to either:
a) limit the  `CollectionViewSource` to output the first 9 items
b) limit the `UniformPanel` to only 3 x 3 and never to create new rows
c) limit the `ItemsControl` to only allow 9 data templates to be created at once.

I'm really scratching my head because I'm sure this is a common databinding scenario but I can't find anything on the web about it.

Comment: Based on the answer of cwap, I have scrapped the CollectionViewSource entirely and just created a master list and a filtered list in the view model, the latter being updated when the search term changes.

Using a converter is a good idea and probably more "pure" MVVM than including the maximum number of outputs in the VM (why I marked it as answer), but for now I'm happy with doing it in the VM.

Cheers for the replies all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two solutions I can think of:

If you are using View Model, put the logic in there to create a property that you can bind to that only ever has 9 elements. Make sure it's unit tested to ensure more than 9 elements never sneak into the collection.

Alternatively you could use a [converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#data_conversion) when binding the items source to convert the full list to a reduced list of the first 9.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that the converter approach prevents change events propagating. If you add or remove from your bound data source it will not be reflected.

Answer (score 2):

This is just one of those things you can't do in XAML (yet).

You could create a "CollectionViewSourceView" (:P), which will be updated whenever CollectionViewSource is updated, to only output the first 9 items. Still, this is going into the codebehind (or better, the viewmodel).

Answer (score 1):

I was about to say the same as James Hay (use a Converter), but I would also add that you can databind a ConverterParameter in the XAML to dynamically specify how many items are returned.